# Is It possible to change URL via AJAX in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

My current URL is `http://localhost/create-story/galleries/wedding`
Want to Make URL is `http://localhost/create-story/galleries/wedding?query=VALUE_FROM_AJAX_RECIEVER`

My Ajax function is

```
function liveSearch(val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('search_wedding') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {query: val},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#gallery').html(data);
        }
    })
}

$('#btn-bridal').on('click', function () {
    liveSearch($(this).text());
});
```

Is It possible to change URL from AJAX after success? want to add request value In Url. Thanks

Comment: https://usefulangle.com/post/81/javascript-change-url-parameters

Comment: You need to redirect using `location.href`

Comment: Hi GaloisGirl, I make the url from your link. How can I set now? any way?

Comment: Hi Ehsan, How to redirect ```location.href``` without loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick for you:

```
function liveSearch(val) {
    let url =  "{{ route('search_wedding') }}?query=" + val;
    window.location = url;
}

$('#btn-bridal').on('click', function () {
    liveSearch($(this).text());
});
```

If it doesn't work please comment it and I will delete the answer if it's not bringing any result.

Comment: It's nice to share the solution and give back to community... can you describe how did you solve it?

Comment: when I use AJAX. I faced problems with pagination. Then I Used get method with request variable and redirect to new route. That's my solution. Ajax didn;t work for me. Because I can't use pagination when I use AJAX.

Comment: So did you use something like I've written in my answer or something completely different?

Comment: Yes. completely Different.

Comment: I fully removed ajax from project.

Comment: I dont have ajax in my answer... maybe you could review my answer and comment on it.

Comment: I don't use any Javascript that's why I didn't know it works or not. I change my coding. I think You are code will work well. that's why I voted you and accept your answer.